# Can i use a select statement for a where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to use a where condition with another select statement in a query. For example:

```
WHERE main_section ='Supplier' AND type_of_pay ='Advance' AND 
((select final_dateofpay FROM com_payments
WHERE main_section ='Supplier') IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Can you show the rest of your query? JOINs might be more relevant to you that sub-selects.

Comment: Yeah. That should work.

Comment: Looks a bit odd. What are you trying to do? Take a look at `EXISTS` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a subquery like that in your where clause because your code

`(select final_dateofpay FROM com_paymentsWHERE main_section ='Supplier')` 
returns more than one row. So, it cannot be directly combined with `IS NOT NULL`
. Remember where clause operates at row level.

However, I think that you want to check whether the subquery return results or not. In that case, you can use it like this

`WHERE main_section ='Supplier' AND type_of_pay ='Advance' AND 
 exists (select final_dateofpay FROM com_payments
WHERE main_section ='Supplier')`

Answer (score 1):

The SQL standard allows a whole host of *sub-query* expressions with statements like `IN (...)`, `NOT IN (...)` , `EXISTS (...)` and `NOT EXISTS(...)`.

In this case the query would be:

```
WHERE main_section ='Supplier' AND type_of_pay ='Advance' AND 
  EXISTS (select final_dateofpay FROM com_payments
    WHERE main_section ='Supplier'))
```

The effect of this query would be that you either would get no rows because there doesn't exist any `com_payments` with `main_section 'Supplier'` or all original rows because one does exist.

The reason for this strange result is that you do not reference any fields from the containing `select` statement in your sub-query. When you add a filter in the sub-query `where` referencing the main query you will probably get the result you are aiming for.